# Why isn't my List inside an object contained within another list getting back to the Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-binding, razor, nested-lists

I'm sure that this has been answered at some point somewhere on SO, but I haven't been able to find it after over an hour of looking.

I'm using C#, MVC3, and AJAX/jQuery.

I have a custom object called FormulaModel that has a few properties and a List of Variables. Inside that List of Variables is a Category and a List of OptionsPairs. Inside that List of OptionPairs is a OptionPair consisting of a Name and a Value.

I have a partial view to show the Formula, and an EditorTemplate for the Variable and OptionPair.

Everything displays as expected, with textboxes for the OptionPairs' Values. However, upon submitting the form that wraps the partial view, I am not getting the list of OptionPairs inside the Variable. FormCollection shows that the values are there in what looks to be the correct format, but the Model does not contain the list of OptionPairs. What am I doing wrong? Am I overlooking something stupid, or trying to do something more complex than regular databinding can handle?

Your assistance is greatly appreciated!

I'll snip out some standard stuff for sake of brevity.

--- Formula.cs ---

```
public int formulaId { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public string formulaCypher { get; set; }
public System.DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
public bool isActive { get; set; }
```

--- FormulaVariable.cs ---

```
[Serializable]
public class FormulaVariable
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public List<OptionPair> Options;
}
```

--- OptionPair.cs ---

```
[Serializable]
public class OptionPair
{
    public string OptionName { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

--- FormulaModel.cs ---

```
private Formula _formula;
public List<FormulaVariable> Variables { get; set; }
public Formula MyFormula
{
    get { return _formula; }
    set { _formula = value; }
}

public void DecodeFormula()
{
    this.VariableList = this.DecodeFormula(this._formula.formulaCypher);
}

public void EncodeFormula()
{
    _formula.formulaCypher = EncodeFormula(this.VariableList);
}
```

--- EditFormula.cshtml ---

```
@model Models.FormulaModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveFormula", "Management", new { area = "Admin" }, null, new { id = "frmManageFormula" }))
{
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MyFormula.dateCreated)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MyFormula.dateEdited)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MyFormula.dateEnacted)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MyFormula.dateRetired)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MyFormula.dealerId)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MyFormula.formulaId)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MyFormula.isActive)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MyFormula.name)

<table style="border: 0; padding: 2px; border-spacing: 2px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                Formula "@Model.MyFormula.name" 
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Variables)
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="button" id="btnSaveFormula" value="Save" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
}
```

--- FormulaVariable.cshtml ---

```
@model Models.FormulaVariable
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid #000000;">
        @Model.Category
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Category)        
    </td>
</tr>
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Options)
```

--- OptionPair.cshtml ---

```
@model Models.OptionPair
<tr>
    <td>
        @Model.OptionName
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.OptionName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Value, new { style = "width: 75px;" })        
    </td>
</tr>
```

--- jQuery ---

```
$("#btnSaveFormula").click(function btnSaveFormula_Click(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $("#frmManageFormula").attr("action"),
        data: $("#frmManageFormula").serialize(),
        success: function (content) {
            alert(content);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

--- Controller Method ----

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveFormula(FormulaModel model, FormCollection formFields)
{
    string errorMsg = string.Empty;
    try
    {   
        model.EncodeFormula();
        errorMsg = model.SaveFormulaCypher();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return Json(errorMsg);
}
```

--- Model Before Hitting View ---

[image: Model Before Hitting View]

--- Model After Getting Back ---

[image: Model After Getting Back]

--- FormCollection After Getting Back ---

[image: FormCollection After Getting Back]

Once again, thank you for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: What's the `ScoringFormulaModel` class? And, yes, could you show a screenshot of what's being posted?

Comment: Whoops.. Sanitizing code and I missed a couple spots as I see now. Edits screenshots coming shortly.